# Stuck in a Inducutive proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

Hi I have this so far but im a little unsure on how should I write to continue, a ny hint would be greatful since I'm learning recently:

Prove, using induction, that the sum of the cubes of three consecutive natural numbers is divisible by nine, that is, that $(n-2)^3 + (n-1)^3 + n^3 = 9 $ , (x) for some $x \in \mathbb{N} $.

Base case:( n = 2 )

$(2-2)^{3} + (2-1)^{3} +2^{3} = 0^{3} + 1^{3} + 2^{3} = 0+1+ 8 = 9$

Which is true because it is divisible by 9.

P.I: Sup. $(n-2)^{3}+(n-1)^{3}+n^{3} = 9x $ so with n+1\
$((n+1)-2)^{3}+((n+1)-1)^{3}+(n+1)^{3} = 9x $

I think it's supposed to continue with the $(3+2)-2 ^{3}$ etc... but after?

Comment: Seems related to the question [Is my inductive proof correct?, $(n-2)^3 + (n-1)^3 + n^3 = 9 \, (x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4827418/89922)?

Comment: @peterwhy oh! so it'll be something like $(n-1)^{3}+n^{3}+(n+1)^{3} \\
(n-1)^{3}+n^{3}+((n-2)+3)^{3} \\
(n-1)^{3}+n^{3}+(n-2)^{3}+9(n-2)^{2}+27(n-2)+27
$

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: TY @peterwhy although why the n-2 is there? I saw a question in other site that added and substracted a (n-2)² as well kinda?

Comment: Let's continue the discussion [at that answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4827423/89922), so that author can also help.

Comment: @peterwhy omg I thought I've already sent my question in another tab but nope,  I  did now haha